# how update one linux system by another linux system in one disk?

Tags: linux

my case is :
i install two linux in  one disk.
i install the first in /dev/sda1  ,then second in /dev/sda2
then i run the fisrt system, i write a script to update the first system when it running.

```
    cd /
    mkdir newroot
    mount /dev/sda2 /newroot
    mount --bind /proc /newroot/proc/
    mount --bind /sys /newroot/sys/
    mount --bind /dev /newroot/dev/
    mount --bind /run /newroot/run/
    chroot /newroot /bin/bash --login 

    mkdir oldroot
    mount /dev/sda1 oldroot
    mount -o remount,rw /oldroot
    rm -rf /oldroot/*
    #but i can't rm the dev proc sys run
    tar -xzpvf /newroot/update/sda1.tar.gz  -C /oldroot/*
```

my question is i can't run the script auto, it will  stop after

run chroot /newroot /bin/bash --login

Answer (score 0):

the commands you want to execute in the chroot cannot be put just after the others. You are executing a different bash, thus you have to feed it a new script. Try this:

```
cd /
mkdir newroot
mount /dev/sda2 /newroot
mount --bind /proc /newroot/proc/
mount --bind /sys /newroot/sys/
mount --bind /dev /newroot/dev/
mount --bind /run /newroot/run/
chroot /newroot /bin/bash --login <<EOF

mkdir oldroot
mount /dev/sda1 oldroot
mount -o remount,rw /oldroot
rm -rf /oldroot/*
#but i can't rm the dev proc sys run
tar -xzpvf /newroot/update/sda1.tar.gz  -C /oldroot/*
EOF
```

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) for an explanation of `<<EOF`